# IBM Cloud Functions + Cloudant (using Python)

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-functions

I've an IBM Cloud Functions action called review. This action takes some information from a Cloudant database. If I run this action on IBM Cloud Functions web interface, I get the desired results, see picure below, then the action function is OK:

[image: IBM CF web dashboard]

And then, if I call this action from web browser, postman, web app, anything I got status 200 (because I specified return of headers, body and statusCode otherwise i'll get 204 (no content)), but if you check, body content returns [] and if you look for first picure, have some informations like car_make, car_model, dealershipt, etc...

[image: Postman API Call] (this API requires dealerId = 15)

This is the endpoint: https://us-east.functions.appdomain.cloud/api/v1/web/c1b04453-0e1d-493b-a3a7-02f5dd95feba/dealership-package/review

This is the expected result when call over postman or directly on web browser.

[image: expected result]

Comment: Thanks for setting up my post. I'm still learning how this works. =)

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary parse to int.

`dealer_id = int(params["dealerId"])`

If the query use int object.

Answer (score 0):

You miss the suffix. To have a JSON response append `.json` to the http request, like so:
https://us-east.functions.appdomain.cloud/api/v1/web/c1b04453-0e1d-493b-a3a7-02f5dd95feba/dealership-package/review.json